# What does shift->{o} = $o; do in Perl?

Tags: perl

What this line in subroutine mean?

```
shift->{o} = $o;
```

I know what shift usualy do, but don't understand it in this context, with dash and arrow.

Comment: `my $self = shift @_; $self->{o} = $o;`

Answer (score 10):

Inside a sub/method,

```
shift
```

is short for

```
shift(@_)
```

A sub call places the arguments in `@_`. A method call does the same, but precedes the arguments with the invocant.

If this is in a sub called as a sub, it assigns `$o` to the element `o` of the hash referenced by the first argument.

If this is in a sub called as a method, it assigns `$o` to the element `o` of the hash referenced by the invocant. Effectively, this sets an attribute `o` of the object on which this method was called.

In the process, `shift` removes the reference from `@_`, though I suspect that might be of no consequence.

Comment: @Borodin, First I explained `shift`, then `@_`, then `->`, which is the only order with no forward references. Do you actually have constructive criticism to offer, are you trolling me as usual?

Comment: I hope you understand that explaining everything in sight doesn't make for a useful answer. I am sure you have seen code where the comments detract from the readability? And removing forward references is for computers, not for people: have you read Wuthering Heights? I believe your answer could be very much more useful if it explained the bigger ideas before their derivation. `ysth`'s answer is pretty much all that is necessary.

Comment: @Boridin, I find ysth's answer completely useless. I don't see how it helps the OP in the least. He doesn't even touch the confusing part of the snippet

Answer (score 4):

Interprets the value shifted as a hashref and assigns a value for the 'o' key in that hash.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a value to subroutine you can get that value in two ways.

1. you can use shift. when passing a single value.
2. If you pass more value. you can get it through array...

shift->{0} is getting a single value (or) first value of passing argument to subroutine.

$0 is for getting the current path of your program.